# Resources for sizing and spacing for dock pilings

Tags: repair, concrete, wood

I have a lot of aging dock built on top of pressure treated 4x4s pilings driven into the lakebed for a permanent dock. I'm looking to understand some of the design around docks; namely sizing, spacing, depth, and load considerations. Mostly to confirm the previous design or understand how it should be improved.

I mention the 4x4s because when looking for piling information much of it is for 12" round posts. I've had a harder time finding resources at a smaller scale that do not reference 2" metal pipe, which is something I'm looking to avoid.